# makefile auto removing .o files

Tags: c++, makefile

I am taking a C++ course in college and they want us to manually type in all of the test files... I know, however, that there is a way to do it with out, which is how I ended up with the [current](http://pastebin.com/6d9UtKM4)(http://pastebin.com/6d9UtKM4) makefile. My question is, why is this makefile automatically removing all the .o files it uses for compiling when it is done? It's not killing me, but I would like to preserve the .o files. I have pasted the makefile [here](http://pastebin.com/6d9UtKM4)(http://pastebin.com/6d9UtKM4). I have also pasted the current result of running "make tests" [here](http://pastebin.com/h3Ny3dib)(http://pastebin.com/h3Ny3dib). (Note the part at the bottom of that page that removes all the .o files automatically.)

I would also like to be able to make it generate it like this:

- g++ -o compileDir/assembler.o -c -Wall src/assembler.cpp
- g++ -o compileDir/string.o -c -Wall src/string.cpp
- g++ -c -Wall -o compileDir/test_assignment.o testSrc/test_assignment.cpp
- g++ -o testDir/test_assignment compileDir/test_assignment.o compileDir/string.o compileDir/assembler.o
- g++ -c -Wall -o compileDir/test_bracket.o testSrc/test_bracket.cpp
- g++ -o testDir/test_bracket compileDir/test_bracket.o compileDir/string.o compileDir/assembler.o
- testDir/test_bracket
- testDir/test_assignment

In other words, I want it to compile everything, then run everything. I hope this isn't too much to ask!

Edit: Additional Information: (This is the code that does "make tests")

```
tests: assembler.o string.o $(test_output) $(test_stringOutput)
        @echo '--- Testing complete ---'

$(testDir)%: $(compileDir)%.o string.o
        g++ -o $@ $< $(compileDir)string.o $(compileDir)assembler.o
        $@
        @echo ''

$(compileDir)%.o: $(testSourceDir)%.cpp
        g++ -c -Wall -o $@ $<

$(compileDir)%.o: $(testStringSrc)%.cpp
        g++ -c -Wall -o $@ $<
```

EDIT: -----------------------------------------

Resolved via comments:

Adding this line fixed it:
.PRECIOUS $(compileDir)%.o

Comment: You're not running `make clean` each time, are you?

Comment: No, i'm just running make tests. The output that is the final link there (http://pastebin.com/h3Ny3dib) is the result of typing make tests

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might add

```
.PRECIOUS: %.o
```

which should be implicit, but perhaps you've got a weird setup.

Comment: I added this line, but it still removes all .o files. Is there a specific spot I should add this?

Comment: No, it could go anywhere. If that didn't work, then either *something* is removing them deliberately, or maybe they're being generated somewhere you don't expect?

Comment: Yeah, perhaps as simple as `.PRECIOUS: obj/*.o` :)

Comment: I haven't typed anything in the makefile that consists of rm without a -f flag on it. But I posted the lines that are creating the tests. (The tests are made entirely through variables.) I am compiling an entire directory.

Comment: I don't know why this mattered or if maybe you have to do it with % instead of *, but I used .PRECIOUS: $(compiledir)%.o and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Just reread the manual and got this line: You can also list the target pattern of an implicit rule (such as ‘%.o’) as a prerequisite file of the special target .PRECIOUS to preserve intermediate files created by rules whose target patterns match that file's name.

Answer (score 7):

Make treats your `.o` files as intermediate and removes them. You can prevent automatic deletion of those by adding them a dependency of the special `.SECONDARY` target. See [Chains of Implicit Rules](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/make/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules) for more details. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I marked the other answer as right, because it solved the problem, but your answer is informative. (Although I read the manual, I just wasn't sure how to use it, since it wasn't working.)

Comment: I think you're right. It's because the test_*.o files aren't used as dependencies anywhere that they're not considered .PRECIOUS. If the makefile was structured in a more traditional way using implicit dependencies, this wouldn't happen.